# Jquery Plugin - Stuck at a point, events issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I am trying to write a simple jquery plugin where in - it will have a textarea or textbox and some button.

On clicking the button I need to get the value of the relevant textarea or textbox.

I have written some code, but I am stuck at a point.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/655wz/

```
(function ($) {

$.fn.widgetify = function (options) {
    var defaults = {
        multi: false
    };
    var settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

    return this.each(function () {
        //create all dom elements here
        this.template = $("<div class='outer' id='" + settings.id + "'>Sample Class</div>");
        this.textbox = $("<input type='text' name='sample' id='sample' />");
        this.textarea = $("<textarea name='sampletextarea' id='sampletextarea'></textarea>");
        this.go = $("<input type='button' name='" + settings.id + "_go' id='" + settings.id + "_go' value='Go' />");

        //append all dom elements here
        if (settings.multi) {
            $(this.template).append(this.textarea);
        } else {
            $(this.template).append(this.textbox);
        }
        $(this.template).append(this.go);
        $(this).append(this.template);

        //all events stuff here
        this.go.on('click', $.proxy(function () {
            //use original 'this'
            alert($(this.textarea).val());
        }, this));

        return this;
    });
}

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: What point are you stuck at? What's the current state of your plugin, and what's the goal?

Comment: whenever I am putting any value in textarea and trying to get that value, its not showing that value in the alert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to fix your html and not repeat your div id. Change the second div to:

```
<div id="example-widget-container1"></div>
```

The rest of the code looks fine. At least as far as the example goes.

Also, in your click handler you would have to alert textarea and textbox values depending upon your settings.multi variable.

Answer (score 0):

I've found two reasons.

A) As prevously mentioned my uchamp about the ID. You should change it in HTML and JS.

B) On `Go.click` function you have only called

```
alert($(this.textarea).val());
```

So, Now text area is working fine, Textbox will not work. You may want to add

```
alert($(this.textbox).val());
```

to make it work.

Comment: @uchamp comment figured out that and modified code as per that.

Answer (score 0):

there is two problems,
first you must add the id in all the inputs

```
    this.textbox = $("<input type='text' name='sample" + settings.id + "' id='sample" + settings.id + "' />");
    this.textarea = $("<textarea name='sampletextarea" + settings.id + "' id='sampletextarea" + settings.id + "'></textarea>");
```

and second you must check your multi boolean

```
             if (settings.multi) {
            alert($(this.textarea).val());
        } else {
           alert($(this.textbox).val());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have bind you plugin twice with `"#example-widget-container"`, thats why you are not getting the correcr output.

Second, You already have dom textarea and dom textbox so need not to do

```
alert($(this.textarea).val());
```

instead

```
this.go.on('click', $.proxy(function () {
                //use original 'this'
                if (settings.multi) {
                    alert(this.textarea.val());
                } else {
                    alert(this.textbox.val());
                }

            }, this));
```

would work.

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/655wz/7/)